# How to generate ArrayList access methods in Java classes by JAXB through XSD

Tags: java, jaxb, xmlbeans, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am trying to replace XMLBeans with JAXB. Currently XMLBeans generates `sizeOf`, `new` and `add` methods for `maxoccur = unbound`.

Through JAXB I am able to generate Java classes and interfaces containing getter and setter methods but ArrayList access methods are not getting generated. I am using global bindings customization

```
<jxb:globalBindings generateValueClass="false" 
    collectionType="java.util.ArrayList" generateElementProperty="false"/>
```

Can anyone tell me if there is some property that needs to be added for this in the global bindings file?